# Is it possible to get the cursor position at driver level on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, driver, mouse

Can a mouse diver use a driver level solution to retrieve the current cursor position ?

I'm now developing a virtual mouse project .It's a virtual hid driver .By installing this driver ,it simulates a mouse on my computer ,I can found it in the device manager (it's a virtual device ,don't actually exists).

Then I can use the writefile() function to tell this driver to do driver level operations for me, like move the mouse to (0,0) .This driver would produce an irp and complete it ,then the mouse moved .

I wonder if I can use a readfile() function to tell this driver to retrieve the current cursor position to me.I don't want to use the GetCursorPos() function ,I want the driver do this job on my behalf ,is that possible ?

Let's say I already have a real mouse that I sometimes use it ;a program constantly use SendInput() functions to send mouse moves on the application layer; and a virtual mouse driver trying to figure out the actual position of the mouse .

Can I achieve that? Isn't there a global variable somewhere in the windows system which stores the current position of the mouse that I can just read it on driver level ?

Comment: _"without running a .exe ?"_ What do you actually mean? If you can hook it from a `.dll`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry ,my bad .I edited the question .